# Is it possible to call (:subdomain => false ) on current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

In my header I have this:

```
<%= link_to "My profile", current_user %>
```

Is there anyway to call (:subdomain => false) or something similar on it so it will escape a subdomain when in it?  I'm using devise.

It works perfectly in these instances:

```
<%= link_to 'About', about_url(:subdomain => false) %>
```

But because it doesn't have '_path' or '_url' in it, I keep getting a 'wrong number of arguments 1 for 0' error.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `link_to` with the `user_url(current_user)` helper instead of the `current_user` shortcut.

I guess this would work :

`<%= link_to "My profile", user_url(current_user, :subdomain => false) %>`.